# Python, Template from string, save 'bool' type

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I use template from string, for example:

```
from string import Template

s = Template(u'(True, $type)')
res = s.substitute(type={'type': bool})
print res
```

Output:

```
(True, {'type': <type 'bool'>})
```

But, I need:

```
(True, {'type': bool})
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, `bool` is a builtin callable in Python so is an object... have you tried just passing a string? `type='bool'` ?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question. If I tried type={'type': 'bool'}, my result: {'type': 'bool'}

Comment: I meant literally `.subtitute(type='bool')` you're passing a dictionary as you're doing it at the moment...

Comment: Use exactly the string that you want, instead of relying on the dict-to-string conversion: `res = s.substitute(type="{'type': bool}")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> res = s.substitute(type="{'type': bool}")
>>> res
u"(True, {'type': bool})"
```

Comment: Ok, it's work, thanks. But now I have little bit another question, how wrap this dictionary in string automatically? I just filled this dictionary dynamically and want use it in template.

Comment: If I try: str = {'type': bool} and res= "%s" % str2 In result, also: "{'type': <type 'bool'>}"